# M2: What's the difference between the view/frontend/email and the view/frontend/templates/email directory?

Tags: magento2, template, email-templates

I get frequently confused with those directories. Yesterday, I copied an email template file in the wrong one of the two folders, - and a colleague was quite upset. How can I avoid making such mistakes, and which files go into the `frontend/email` vs. the `frontend/templates/email` directory?

Comment: I think you want to override email header or footer template?

Comment: In this specific case, I want to add more html email templates - but that works, already. I want to know in general, what kind of files goes to which of the directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `view/frontend/email` folder, you will see HTML file which is used as an email template.
This is a file you see in the admin panel when you load any email template.
E.g.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/email/order_new.html

Whereas in `view/frontend/templates/email` folder, there will be the dynamic content (**.phtml files**) which are used to add the data in the email templates.
E.g.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items.phtml